# Threads occasionally blocking while writing to the same file

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to read from two text files (having the same number of lines, i.e. 10000) using two separate threads, one file containing Strings and the other containing Integers. Afterwards I want to write in another text file (String,Integer) values from corresponding positions in the result sets, each on a distinct line. For these purposes I'm using two classes implementing the Runnable interface.

The problem I'm facing is that every time I run the program, there is a chance that one of the threads is blocking execution, and I don't understand why considering that I'm using wait() and notify() in a `synchronized` block. More specifically, at times the program runs successfully finishing execution, while in most cases it stops at various stages (e.g. ~3000 out 10000 lines written, or even ~500).

citireInteger is a reference to the other thread which is reading the Integer file.

Here is relevant code from the classes dealing with reading from the String and Integer files, respectively:

```
@Override
public void run(){

    ........
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("rezultat.txt", true)));

        for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++){

            synchronized(this){
                pw.write(strings.get(i));
            }

            synchronized(citireInteger){
                citireInteger.notifyAll();
            }

            try{
                synchronized(this){
                    wait();
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        pw.close();
    }

    synchronized(citireInteger){
        citireInteger.notify();
    }
}
```

The thread reading the Integer file:

```
    public void run(){

    ...........

    try{
        pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("rezultat.txt", true)));

        for(int i = 0; i < ints.size(); i++){

            synchronized(this){
                pw.write(ints.get(i) + '\n');
                System.out.println(ints.get(i));
            }
            synchronized(citireString){
                citireString.notifyAll();
            }

            try{
                synchronized(this){
                    wait();
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        pw.close();
    }

    synchronized(citireString){
        citireString.notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, writing to the same file with multiple threads. I doubt that will gain much of a performance boost.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this, but this is required for academic purposes

Comment: what is citireInteger?

Comment: I edited the question as to answer your question.

Comment: I have one observation about wait(); in the third synchronized block -> shouldn't it make the String reading thread wait until reading the Integer? but I believe it's invoked after the second synchronization not after the end of the first

Comment: If your current thread is made to wait() in 3rd synchronized block, where do you notify it?

Comment: I've added code from the other Thread, which handles reading the values from the Integer file. The String reading thread is being notified in the other thread, and viceversa.

Comment: Perhaps you should write a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that one thread is calling `notifyAll` on the other thread, then getting switched out before synchronizing on its own writer to call `wait`.  The other thread does its write, synchronizes on its writer, and calls `wait`.  Then the first thread gets switched in again, synchronizes on its writer, and calls `wait`.  There's your deadlock.

Better would be to have both threads synchronize on the same object to write.  Best would be to store the data in memory in a thread safe way and write from a single thread once reading from both threads was complete.

Answer (score 0):

When you notify the other thread, the other thread will only see that when the other threads is waiting for it. I the other thread is outside that synchronized block, and enters that synchronized block *after* it is notified, it will then wait for a notify that won't happen, or rather, than happened before it started to wait for it.
It's hard to really determine what the objective of this exercise is, but I'm guessing it is about two threads taking turns doing a write. Ok, so, how about making the synchronized(citireInt/String) block encompass its entire code! This way, the other thread trying to obtain a lock will ONLY get that lock WHEN the other thread is waiting. That I think would guarantee no blocking and the result would be both threads taking turns, one by one.

Edit: not entirely exactly as I described, but the key points is where to synchronize...

```
   public void run()
   {
       ...........

       try
       {
           pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("rezultat.txt", true)));

           synchronized(this)
           {
               for(int i = 0; i < ints.size(); i++)
               {
                   pw.write(ints.get(i) + '\n');
                   System.out.println(ints.get(i));

                   synchronized (citireString)
                   {
                       citireString.notifyAll();
                   }

                   try
                   {
                       wait();
                   }
                   catch (InterruptedException e)
                   {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Throwable e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       finally
       {
           pw.close();
       }
    }
```

Comment: ... just to clarify. Just before the for statement, have the synchronized(citireString) block start. The entire for loop itself goes inside that whole synchronized block. Same for the other thread. The wait citireString.notifyAll() line however, stays right where it is, except you don't have a second synchronized for that, because you're already inside that.